# Trying to create a collation on Postgres 9.6; a nonsensical error message

Tags: postgresql, collation, localization, docker

I'm running Postgres 9.6.1 on a Debian-based Docker image. My default locale is `en_US.utf8`. I'm trying to create a collation of type `ja_JP.utf8`. I have the Japanese locale installed as demonstrated by the command `locale -a`:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
ja_JP.utf8
POSIX
```

However, when trying to create the Japanese collation in psql, I get the following, nonsensical error message:

```
# create collation ja_JP (LOCALE="ja_JP.utf8");
ERROR:  could not create locale "ja_JP.utf8": Success
```

Googling a bit finds me a bug report from over two years back: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20140525154511.GA21233%40alap3.anarazel.de

It looks the same, and judging from my symptoms, it isn't fixed yet! Is there any way to work around this bug?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround: the bug happens only if an earlier attempt to create a collation has failed. After a failure, the bug seems to keep happening until the server process is restarted. So to create the collation, you have to get it right from the start, or restart the process to try again. To restart a Docker container, use

```
docker restart $DB_CONTAINER_NAME_HERE
```